# UIActivityViewController: LaunchServices: invalidationHandler called

Tags: uiactivityviewcontroller

i am using `UIActivityViewController` in ios8

and using `ARSafariActivity.h`

```
   NSURL *newsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
    NSString *newsTitle = @"..."

    ARSafariActivity *safariActivity = [[ARSafariActivity alloc] init];

    UIActivityViewController *avc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] 
                                        initWithActivityItems:@[newsTitle, newsURL] 
                                        applicationActivities:@[safariActivity]];

    [avc setRestorationIdentifier:@"Activity"];

    [self.navigationController presentViewController:avc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Everything is working properly, but when i test app in my iPhone the console show this:

**LaunchServices: invalidationHandler called**

How i can fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Seem to be discussed/answered in several threads, e.g. here: [This is a bug on Apple's side](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26189591/3736845)

In short - it's debug message from iOS and you should not care about it